# What is this type of ceiling called?

Tags: ceiling

What are these type of ceilings called?
[image]
These don't have enough height to be called cathedral celling, are these just called exposed beams ?

Comment: I don't know that they're called anything. The t&g is probably the underside of the roof deck; the beams are holding everything up.

Comment: please paste the picture into the question using the provided button, the one that looks like a mountain and moon